# Intellisense in Asp.Net Mvc (Razor) View not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In Asp.Net MVC, I am not getting options Goto View and Add View if I right on Controller. And in View, intelligence is not working for c# code.
Most importantly I am getting a window and message as below

The web project requires missing web components to run with Visual Studio. Would you like to download and install them using the Web Platform Installer now?
(Note: Some components might require restart to take effect.)

Asp.Net web oages with Razor syntax 3.0.0.0

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Intelligence or intellisense?

Comment: intellisense @Sarvesh Mishra

Comment: Corrected. @Markandeyulu

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Asp.net and web tools
[image]
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the web.config in your views folder and compare the `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` version with Runtime `dependentAssembly` in the project web.config.

**View web.config**:

```
type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"
```

**Project Web.Config**:

```
assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"
```

Once they are consistent, the errors should be gone. I hope this helps.